# Clear visual studio debugger's saved connections in attach to process dialog

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, attach-to-process

I need to clear some old entries saved for Connection target dropdown list in Attach to Process dialog.
Some remote servers have been decommissioned. But their names are still listed on the top of Connection target list.
When I start the Debug menu command "Attach to process", it takes awhile trying to connect to an old server that is not connectable.
Google search doesn't return the answer of where the list is saved.

Hopefully someone can provide the answer.

Comment: You can try to reset all settings under Tools>Import and Export Settings.

Answer (score 1):

After quite some digging I've found the answer you might be after (if you still need it), the web page you'll need is at [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170).

If you want to dive straight in have a look in the Tools Menu under Options and then find Cross Platform and Connection Manager:

[image: Connection Manager]

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.4.3 (current version as of Jan 2023) just in case other versions have a different layout.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. My VS 2019 doesn't show any item in it even though its Connection target saved a lot of machine names.

Comment: Sorry, I had what sounded like a similar problem to you in that I have moved the private key file for one of my SSH connections and like you the Attach to Process dialog would take a long time then error. By coming into this dialog, I was able to edit the connection in question and it works properly now.  I thought you may be able to remove or edit the connections you were having issues with and this would help.